# How to get all different neo4j nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In `Neo4j` graph database, i need to get all different nodes properties.

**for example:**
Graph database is having two types of nodes `Student{firstName,lastName}` and `School{name,size}`. And it is having 100 schools and 1000 students.

Now i want to get these details:

```
Student{firstName,lastName}
School{name,size}
```

I am using neo4j Java api. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous, Anyway, I will give it a shot. I use Cypher (I never use Java api) maybe you can use the concept to solve it in neo4j Java api.

```
MATCH (n: Student), (m:School)
RETURN n,m
```

or

```
MATCH (n: Student), (m:School)
RETURN n.firstname as 'First Name', n.lastname as 'Last Name', m.name as 'School Name', m.size as 'Size'
```

Comment: thanks @Olufemi Adeyemi, but i want to get these details from an unknown graph database, school,student i gave it for an example. We are not sure what data is there.

Comment: In case you want to return all the node in db, you can use:

MATCH p=(n)-->(m) 
RETURN extract(j IN nodes(p)) as \`Nodes\`.



After getting the details, you can now refine your query to fit your specific needs

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, to return all nodes, use this instead:

MATCH (n) 
RETURN n

Comment: Note that your queries are creating a cross product between all Student and all School nodes.

Comment: @MichaelHunger, I agree with you, that is why I recommend using Match (n) Return n. As Ramesh already notice, this will take a lot of computing time to iterate through huge data but you can mitigate that by indexing. In reality, I don't see any reason why you will like to return all nodes, it will alway be better if you refine your query to exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

From Cypher

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n
```

From the core java api

```
for (Node n : GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllNodes()) {
   for (String prop: n.getPropertyKeys()) {
      System.out.println(n.getProperty(prop)); 
   }
   for (Label l : n.getLabels()) {
      System.out.println(l); 
   }
}
```

If you just want to see the properties per label and not the values for all nodes I would go with this:

```
match (n:School) return n limit 1;
match (n:Student) return n limit 1;
```

Unfortunately there is not yet a schema information that declares which properties are available per label.

You can use this though to get *all* property-types of your graph:

```
GlobalGraphOperations.at( graphDb ).getAllPropertyKeys()
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hunger, iterating through all the nodes, is in't a performance issue if i have millions of nodes. I have coded exactly but thinking is there any problem.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted to do, to iterate over all nodes and lookup each node's properties and labels

Comment: Yes @Michael Hunger, but is int become a performance issue if we iterate through millions of rows, thanks.